# App Script authorizations associated with Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization

I have managed to incorporate an app into a Google sheet I was able to copy from a tutorial video. The app provides a Custom Menu in the sheet that allows a user to conduct a search of content across the sheet.

The sheet, with editor access and Custom Menu showing, is available here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fl2B9yrZA75Vm5KwVsLsZ4K2_GUYO35LQLYxDcSoauY/edit?usp=share_link

and it works fine even if I may do some more formatting.

The sheet is available via the Search Test button near bottom right on this page:

https://www.victoriasforestryheritage.org.au/resources/records.html

but, as you will see, I am unable to set authorizations in the back end so that any user on the front end can access the sheet with the custom menu showing so they can search the data. The link above shows the sheet, but without the Custom Menu.(The custom Menu appears to work if I prove Editor access, but obviously I do not wish to do that)

The use of Apps Script is totally new to me, and I have searched widely for help, but obviously have found no solution. I read  what I think are the relevant Google documents but I simply do not have the depth of understanding to interpret them.

**In summary, I wish any user of the website to be able to access a linked google sheet and be able to search that sheet using the Apps Script created Custom Menu .**

I am functional with HTML and CSS and just beginning to try and learn some JavaScript. In other words you are corresponding with a relative novice.

I have tried different file access levels as indicated above, I have looked through Apps Script authorization process but frankly I have trouble understanding how and where the Script links to the sheet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Richard

Comment: In your situation, if you want to make the user search values from your shared Spreadsheet, for example, after the Spreadsheet is opened, the user can search by ‎"Ctrl＋F" without authorization. Is this your expected situation? If this was not your expected situation, can I ask you about the detail of your expected situation?

Comment: Thank you but it was not what I was expecting. I may try an add some photos to the post to show what I see and what I am hoping an everyday user can see als.

Comment: Try this link for three photos  - photo1 shows the custom menu (Custom Search) in place on the sheet.  photo 2 shows the table prepared ready for search  photo 3 shows a seacrh done across 6000+ records for the word 'charcoal'.   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ekEDi5aBDssSpeXuu8fxtGbV_asJRSl-?usp=share_link

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. But, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Don't apologize please. I appreciate any feedback - for example I was unaware of the Ctrl +F option in sheets. So I know more than before.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected result from your reply. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution and/or a workaround.